# Qtimer iterations

Tags: c++, qt

Maybe I am overthinking it, but need some help with iterations and qtimer. I have the following QTimer code and function (I have tried to simplify it as much as possible, sorry if some syntax is wrong):

```
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(whateverfunction()));
    timer -> start();

void MainWindow::whateverfunction()
{
checksomething();
if (checksomething() == 1)
{
dosomething1(); //function I want to run ONLY the first time checksomething() = 1
dosomething2(); //function I want to run the second,third,fourth,etc. time checksomething() = 1
}
else
{
donothing(); //if this function is run the count resets, meaning dosomething1() should be run again if checksomething() == 1 again-- but only the first time.
}
}
```

How can I accomplish the above? I have tried introducing a control variable, but each time this function is run via QTimer it resets. Thanks!

Comment: Make the control variable a private member of `MainWindow`, not a automatic variable in `whateverfunction`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend wrapping the call to `dosomething1()` with a [std::call_once](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)

```
std::once_flag flag;

void MainWindow::whateverfunction()
{
checksomething();
if (checksomething() == 1)
{
    std::call_once(flag, [this](){
        dosomething1();
    };
    dosomething2();
}
}
```